# touch events stop firing when dragging down on mobile Safari - ipad html5

Tags: javascript, ipad, html, ios5, webkit

When i add event listeners to account for touch events such as touchmove and touchstart

```
        document.addEventListener("touchstart", function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            document.getElementById("fpsCounter").innerHTML = "touch start";
            trace("touch start");
        }, false);
        document.addEventListener("touchmove", function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var x = event.touches[0].pageX - getCanvasOffset().offsetLeft; 
            var y = event.touches[0].pageY - getCanvasOffset().offsetTop;

            document.getElementById("fpsCounter").innerHTML = "touch touchmove "+x+"  "+y;
            trace("touch touchmove");
        }, false);
        document.addEventListener("touchend", function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            document.getElementById("fpsCounter").innerHTML = "touch end";
            trace("touch touch end");
        }, false);
        document.addEventListener("touchcancel", function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            document.getElementById("fpsCounter").innerHTML = "touch cancel";
            trace("touch touch cancel");
        }, false);

    }
```

touchMove works fine untill i start moving down, since the whole html page starts getting scrolled down by safari. When I release, the html page bounces back to its original position. No elements inside the html page spill outside of the boundry of the ipad. 
How could i prevent the browser's dragging html page functionality? i tries event.preventDefault() with no luck

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Mobilesafari freezes the page when it scrolls

Comment: it has to be possible, if it wasnt, then you wont be able to do drag and drop with html5

Comment: You can't on mobile, it interferes too much

Answer (score 0):

You can try to cancel the event (move than just with preventDefault)

```
event.cancelBubble = true;
event.returnValue = false;
if (event.stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation();
if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
```